# is a vanilla axios npm install considered a legit way to call api's in rn?

Tags: react-native, axios

I've used axios in vanilla React apps which has worked well for me and axios seems to be a popular choice for this purpose.  I did an npm install of axios into my RN app this evening.  I wired it up to call an API and it returned data from the API as expected in my local Android emulator.

Is it really that easy to use axios in RN?  I didn't configure any gradle dependencies or do any other type of special setup step or configuration beyond the basic npm install.  I'm assuming that this setup will run as-is on iOS as well.  If it's really that simple then that makes me pretty happy compared to all the hoops I've had to jump through to get the various firebase modules configured and working properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes most 3rd party modules for React Native are very easy to use and only require you to run npm install - packetname - without touching any native code or extra files like gradle for example.